# Advantages of scipy.linalg.expm over scipy.sparse.linalg.expm?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm having trouble understanding when it would be better to use the sparse version of `expm` over the regular version.

If I take a dense matrix `M`,which happens to be sparse, of size `4000 x 4000` matrix and compute `scipy.linalg.expm(M)`, this takes around 25 seconds. If I then do `M_sparse = sparse.csc_matrix(M)` and compute `scipy.sparse.linalg.expm(M_sparse)`, this runs for at least 10 minutes.

What is the right use case for `scipy.sparse.linalg.expm`? Is it intended for much larger matrices?

Answer (score 3):

`scipy.linalg.expm` uses `sparse.linalg.expm`.  Look at its source:

```
Signature: linalg.expm(A)
Source:   
def expm(A):
    import scipy.sparse.linalg
    return scipy.sparse.linalg.expm(A)
```

We can look at the sparse source as well, though that's a lot longer, since it's doing the real work.  It also handles a number of different cases, including varying degrees of `Pade` approximation.  You may have to read up on that approximation.  If I recall correctly it involves an inverse.

When you say your array is 'sparse', what exactly do you mean?  Already as `scipy.sparse.csr` matrix?  Or a `ndarray` with many 0s?  What proportion of 0s (or nonzeros)? 50% or 5% sparsity?  Sparsity matters a lot when working with `scipy.sparse` matrices.  And (4000,4000) is small by most `sparse` usage.  A dense version will fit in memory, and usually calculate faster.

My guess is that if there's a time difference, it's because of the usage of a sparse matrix versus ndarray, not the calling function.

`expm` on a (4000,4000) array is fairly slow however it's done.

Comment: My original ndarray `M` is "sparse" in the sense that only 1% of its entries are nonzero. It's much, much slower to pass the `scipy.sparse.csr` version of the array to `scipy.linalg.expm` than the original array. So I don't understand the use of sparsity here.

Comment: `expm` (called either way) works with both `ndarray` or sparse matrix.  At your size and sparsity the `ndarray` is faster.  But the sparse times are more sensitive to the sparsity. For example with a .001 sparsity, the `csc` matrix is faster than its `M.A` equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for common algorithm for sparse and dense is just historical.

The situation will change in version 1.9 via https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/15079 and then sparse arrays will use the `sparse.linalg` version and the dense will go through the `linalg.expm`. The typical difference is that you can't supply, say, 25000x25000 dense matrix without exceptionally large memory hardware but if there is sparsity in your array and create a sparse array that fits in the memory then you can use the sparse version that doesn't use dense algorithm, in particular, matrix powers, norm estimation and matvec operations.

With this PR, it will accelarate the dense version further especially smaller matrices up to 10x and also will handle stacked numpy arrays.

The plan is to overhaul all matrix functions, `solve` and `eig` such that the API is unified and usability is increased.